# How to restrict to downgrade in-app subscription plan from the iOS app settings?

Tags: iphone, react-native, in-app-subscription

I don't want user to downgrade the plan from the iOS app settings. User should be allow to only upgrade the plan from the iOS settings.

is it possible? Can we restrict user to not downgrade the plan from the iOS settings?

Do you think is it possible to restrict?